# Show loading instead of body or div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have a simple code to show and load next page with ajax. Before showing the new page, I can show a loading image from `div`, code:

```
<div class="loading"><img src="{THEME}/images/loader.gif" /></div>
```

My content's div are this:

```
<div id="dle-content"></div>
```

Now, my question is, how I can show loading `div` instead of dle-content `div`?

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function nextPage() {
var nextPage = $('#ajax-next-page a').attr('href');
ShowLoading("");
if (nextPage !== undefined) {
$.ajax({
url: nextPage,
success: function(data) {
$('#ajax-next-page').remove();
$('#next-page').remove();
HideLoading("");
$('#dle-content').append($('#dle-content', data).html());
}
})
}
};
</script>
```

I want to make blur or make dark background on dle-content `div` when loading `div` is showing.

Comment: Relax... what's with all the exclamation points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukePj/)

```
function ShowLoading() {
  var img = "loading.gif"; // here define name of image
  var s = document.createElement("div");
  s.style.width = "100%";
  s.style.height = "100%";
  s.style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)";
  s.style.position = "absolute";
  s.style.top = "0px";
  s.style.left = "0px";
  s.id = "wrapper";
  document.body.appendChild(s);
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.src = img;
  image.style.margin = "0 auto";
  document.getElementById("wrapper").appendChild(image);
}

function HideLoading() {
  $("#wrapper").fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: oh my goodness! but my fingers wrote too big code very difficultly! link to your site?

Comment: It's on localhost for testing :D

Comment: ok enjoy that code but add margins manually for the loading image :D

Answer (score 0):

maybe try sth like

```
            $(".loading").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
            $(this).show();
            $('.dle-content').hide
        }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $('.dle-content').show
        })
```